# multiple inheritance

Tags: c++

when we say "a member declated as protected is accessible to any class imediately derived from it" what does this mean. 
in the follwing example get_number function can be accessible by the result class , as per the statement it sould only be accessile to test class.

```
class student
{    
protected:
    int roll_number;        
public:
    void get_number(int){ cout<< "hello"; }
    void put_number(void) {cout<< "hello"; }
};

class test : public student
{
protected:
    float sub1;
    float sub2;
public:     
    void get_marks(float, float) {cout<< "hello"; roll_number  = 10; }    
    void put_marks(void) {cout<< "hello"; cout << "roll_number = " << roll_number  ; } 
};

class result : public test
{
   float total;
public:
    void display(){cout<< "hello"; roll_number  = 10; }
};

int main()
{
    result student;
    student.get_marks(2.2, 2.2);
    student.put_marks();
    return 0;
}
```

i changed the code as per the first statement the protected variable roll_number not be accessible upto the result class ?

Comment: Note: This isn't multiple inheritence - it's just single inheritance in a chain.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `get_number` as public so all classes can see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `class result` to not have direct access to data member `roll_number` you need to change the inheritance access of `class test` to `protected`:

```
class test : protected student
{
};
```

For more information, see [The C++ FAQ Lite: Public and Private Inheritance](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html).  Changing how `class test` inherits from `class student` also affects how data members in `class student` are accessed by classes derived from `class test`.

An alternative to inheritance is for `class test` to contain a private pointer to an instance of `class student`, *as long as `class student` is not an abstract class*.